# How did the Ninja Koopas become giant?

Tags: super-mario-brothers

In the first episode of *The Adventures of Super Mario Bros 3*, the Ninja Koopas are sent to dispatch a giant mushroom man. When they get there they are the same size as the giant.

I can't remember how they became giant themselves, if it was explained at all?

Comment: I'm not sure why this is coming up in the Close Votes queue as 'off topic'. Asking for plot explanations in video games is perfectly on topic.

Comment: @Mithrandir - Plus it's asking about a TV series. Duh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was addressed in the Season 3 premier episode [Sneaky Lying Cheating Giant Ninja Koopas](https://www.mariowiki.com/Sneaky_Lying_Cheating_Giant_Ninja_Koopas). King Koopa uses magic on his henchmen to make them large.

> *A panicking Bully is suddenly pushed forward by Kootie Pie Koopa. As
> King Koopa prepares to zap the protesting Bully with his wand, he
> orders Big Mouth, Cheatsy and Kooky von Koopa to step forward. As
> Kootie Pie, Hip and Hop Koopa back away, King Koopa zaps Bully,
> Cheatsy, Kooky and Big Mouth with his wand, turning them gigantic and
> inexplicably giving them weapons and ninja costumes. King Koopa then
> commands his colossal children to go out and kidnap Prince Hugo so he
> can conquer Giant Land.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Mariowiki](https://www.mariowiki.com/Sneaky_Lying_Cheating_Giant_Ninja_Koopas)</sup></sub>